# How to create two radio buttons for the same required property C# MVC Razor

Tags: validation, razor, model-view-controller, radio-button, required

I have a model with a required property called EmploymentStatus. I want to create two radio buttons using Html.RadioButtonFor in a Razor page. Here is the HTML that I have currently:

```
<div class="control-group--small">
    <label class="control-label align-center">Are you self-employed?</label>
    <label class="control control-radio">
        Self-Employed
                @Html.RadioButton("BorrowerEmploymentStatus", "Self-Employed", false)
        </label>
        <label class="control control-radio">
                Not Self-Employed
                @Html.RadioButton("BorrowerEmploymentStatus", "Not Self-Employed", false)
        </label>
</div>
```

Here is my model property:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Yes or No if you are self-employed or not.")]
[DisplayName("Are you self-employed?")]
public string EmploymentStatus { get; set; }
```

The problem is that the Html.RadioButton only puts the required validation on the first radio button. So if someone were to select 'Not Self Employed' the model property gets set, but the ModelState is invalid because the validation was put on the radio button that was not selected.

First Html.RadioButton generates:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select Yes or No if you are self-employed or not." name="BorrowerEmploymentStatus" type="radio" value="Self-Employed">
```

And the second Html.RadioButton generates:

```
<input name="BorrowerEmploymentStatus" type="radio" value="Not Self-Employed">
```

So my question is how do you have two radio buttons, for the same required model property and keep the ModelState valid?

Comment: What you are seeing is the correct behavior. The `data-val-*` attributes should only be on the first radio button, and it not clear why you think it should be on the second.

Comment: But you code can never bind to to your model - you are generating a `name` attribute that has no relationship to your model (`BorrowerEmploymentStatus` is not `EmploymentStatus`). ALWAYS use the string typed methods - `<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.EmploymentStatus, "Self-Employed", new { id = "" })<span>Self-Employed</span></label>`. However a `bool IsSelfEmployed` property rather than a `string` seems more appropriate for this

Comment: How then do I validate that the field is set if the second radio button is selected? In the controller, the value of property is set to the value of the second radio button, but the ModelState is invalid because the required flag is on the first one. How would I inform the ModelState that is should be valid when it has no idea about the second radio button?

Comment: Read my comments carefully. And `data-val-*` attributes have nothing whatsoever to do with `ModelState` which is server side. `The `data-val-*` attributes are used by jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` to add rules to `jquery.validate.js` for client side validation. They are only required on the first radio button. When you post your form it sends back a name/value pair for the property.

Comment: If you select the 1st radio button it sends `EmploymentStatus=Self-Employed` and the property has a value of `"Self-Employed"`. If you select the 2nd it sends `EmploymentStatus=Not Self-Employed` and the property has a value of `"Not Self-Employed"`. In both cases the property has a value and its valid. If you do not select any, then no value is sent and a `ModelState` error is added because of the `[Required]` attribute.